# Rails 4.2 : image path trouble in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Following is a part of my code. background images are not being loaded.i've tried things like  '<%= asset_path("images/bg1.jpg") %>' and "images/bg1.jpg" etc .I'm new in rails can anyone point me in right direction ?

```
$(".login-bg").backstretch(["bg1.jpg","bg2.jpg","bg3.jpg"],{fade:1e3,duration:8e3})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the demo:

```
$.backstretch([
      "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

Apparently, your code won't work because all you are doing is passing in strings. Instead what you want to do is pass in routes that serve your images.

Assuming that you have this in a javascript file, you won't be able to use your rails helper. What you would have to do in this case is:

- Build a controller that serves these images: `ImagesController`
- Just upload the pictures onto an online cloud and put the links inside the array

Alternatively, what you should be able to do is write a `script` inside the view (html.erb) and you should be able to access the rails helper this way. Then you would be able to interpolate the links as a string.

ie `"[#{image_path('bg1.jpg')}", "#{image_path('bg2.jpg')}"]`

Comment: i've these images in /assets/images/bg1.jpg and i want to access them from there not online

Comment: Then you either want a controller to serve your own images or you need your routes array to include the absolute paths `"my_app.com/assets/bg2.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is Javascript that will be executed from the user's browser, on the user's machine. As such, it will not have direct access to files in the `images` directory on the application server.

If you name your Javascript file `something.js.erb` you can embed Ruby code in it for expansion by the asset pipeline, something like:

```js
$(".login-bg")
  .backstretch(
    ["<%= image_url('bg1.jpg') %>",
     "<%= image_url('bg2.jpg') %>",
     "<%= image_url('bg3.jpg') %>"
    ],
    { fade: 1e3, duration: 8e3 }
  )
```

The Rails [asset pipeline guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) is an excellent source of information about how to use these features.